# Trying to separate or isolate functionality from one another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically the functionality or slider I'm building tends to trigger other sliders. So if I click on the `next` button. All other sliders will slide. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can separate or isolate the functionality from one another using `.each()` and `this` so that if I create multiple elements let say a `slider` it does not affect other elements

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var Slider = {

        init : function() {
            
            this.$sliderBanner = $('.slider-banner');


            $('.slider-banner').each(function() {
                var position = 0;
                this.$sliderItemsWrapper = $('.slider-items' , this);
                this.$slides = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper);
                this.$sliderButtons = $('.arrow');
                this.totalSlides = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper).length;
    
                this.sliderBannerWidth = $(this).width();
                this.$setSliderWrapperWidth = $(this.$sliderItemsWrapper).width( this.sliderBannerWidth * this.totalSlides );
        
                this.$slides.width(this.sliderBannerWidth);
                var that = this;
       
                $('.arrow.-prev').on('click', function(){
                    position --;
                    if ( position == -1 ) { position = that.totalSlides - 1; }
                    that.$sliderItemsWrapper.css('left', - (that.sliderBannerWidth * position));  
                    console.log(position);
                });
    
                $('.arrow.-next').on('click', function() {
                    position ++;
                    if (position == that.totalSlides) { position = 0; }
                    that.$sliderItemsWrapper.css('left', - (that.sliderBannerWidth * position));  
                    console.log(position);
                });                
            });
        },
    };

   
 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        Slider.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

html, body {
  height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey; }

.slides > .image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%; }

.slider-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.5s linear; }
  .slider-items > .slides {
    height: 100%; }

.slider-banner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: beige;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .slider-banner .arrow {
    z-index: 10; }
  .slider-banner .arrow.-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0; }
  .slider-banner .arrow.-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 0; }
  .slider-banner > .slider-items {
    height: 50vh; }

.carousel-wrapper > .carousel-card {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: violet; }
  .carousel-wrapper > .carousel-card:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: saddlebrown; }

.carousel-region {
  background-color: aqua;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .carousel-region > .carousel-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transition: left 0.5s linear; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="slider-banner">
            <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
            <div class="slider-items">

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                        <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="banner-detail">
                <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slider-banner">
            <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
            <div class="slider-items">


                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="slides">
                        <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)"> 

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="banner-detail">
                <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question please? If you want to create individuals components using jquery you can write your Jquery plugin and you can also extend  jquery plugin in your plugin (In your case slider). You can start with Jquery plgins [here](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: @RahulRaut Basically I'm trying to isolate the functionality from one another. Lets say I have multiple sliders and I click on the `next` button. It will not make all the sliders slide next

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix for your code, make sure you're binding to the correct elements.

Change:

`this.$sliderButtons = $('.arrow');` to `this.$sliderButtons = $('.arrow',this);`

`$('.arrow.-prev').on('click', function(){` to `$('.arrow.-prev',this).on('click', function(){`

`$('.arrow.-next').on('click', function(){` to `$('.arrow.-next',this).on('click', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind slider on unique elements(can be done using attribute name, id or unique jQuery selector). Just pass the elements in Slider.Init() as shown in the code. So whenever slider will be initialized for that particular element it will be in the parent div scope and only that particular slider will move.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
 v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/<style>
   html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
   h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
  a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
  del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
  small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
  b, u, i, center,
  dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
  fieldset, form, label, legend,
  table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
  article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
  figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
  time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

html, body {
  height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey; }

.slides > .image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%; }

.slider-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.5s linear; }
  .slider-items > .slides {
    height: 100%; }

.slider-banner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: beige;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .slider-banner .arrow {
    z-index: 10; }
  .slider-banner .arrow.-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0; }
  .slider-banner .arrow.-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 0; }
  .slider-banner > .slider-items {
    height: 50vh; }

.carousel-wrapper > .carousel-card {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: violet; }
  .carousel-wrapper > .carousel-card:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: saddlebrown; }

.carousel-region {
  background-color: aqua;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .carousel-region > .carousel-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transition: left 0.5s linear; } </style>

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div id="div1" class="slider-banner">
            <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
            <div class="slider-items">

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" > 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" > 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                        <div class="image" > 

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="banner-detail">
                <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id ="div2" class="slider-banner">
            <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
            <div class="slider-items">


                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image" > 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides">
                    <div class="image"> 

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="slides">
                        <div class="image" > 

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="banner-detail">
                <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        (function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var Slider = {

        init : function(elementArr) {

            this.$sliderBanner = $('.slider-banner');


            $(elementArr).each(function(index, value) {
                var position = 0;
                var $sliderItemsWrapper = $(value+'.slider-items');
                $sliderItemsWrapper.$slides = $(value+'.slides');
                $sliderItemsWrapper.$sliderButtons = $(value+'.arrow');
                $sliderItemsWrapper.totalSlides = $(value+'.slides').length;

                $sliderItemsWrapper.sliderBannerWidth = $($sliderItemsWrapper).width();
                $sliderItemsWrapper.$setSliderWrapperWidth = $($sliderItemsWrapper).width( $sliderItemsWrapper.sliderBannerWidth * $sliderItemsWrapper.totalSlides );

                $sliderItemsWrapper.$slides.width($sliderItemsWrapper.sliderBannerWidth);
                var that = $sliderItemsWrapper;

                $(value+' .arrow.-prev').on('click', function(){
                    position --;
                    if ( position == -1 ) { position = that.totalSlides - 1; }
                    that.css('left', - (that.sliderBannerWidth * position));  
                    console.log(position);
                });

                $(value+' .arrow.-next').on('click', function() {
                    position ++;
                    if (position == that.totalSlides) { position = 0; }
                   that.css('left', - (that.sliderBannerWidth * position));  
                    console.log(position);
                });                
            });
        },
    };



    $(document).ready(function() {

        Slider.init(["#div1","#div2"]);
    });

})(jQuery);
        </script>
    </div>
```